# Android: float does not getting calculated

Tags: java, android

Currently I'm having a problem, that drives me crazy.

You know, how the percentage is calculated.
It's (p/pMax)*100 , isn't it ?

That is just that, what I've written in code.
But I ALWAYS getting 0.0 as the result of this calculation.
See the screenshot for clarifying.

[eclipse screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SToFO.png)

As you can see the float variable *prg* becomes *0.0* as the result of the calculation *(252/1944)*100*

What am I doing wrong ?
If you want, I can put the variable initialization here.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: progress and progressMax are both int?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

252/1944 is treated as an int division even though you are putting the result in a double. 
Try 252.0/1944.0

In the case of variables, just cast them as doubles or floats
(e.g. (double) a / (double) b )

LE: I should clarify that, like the others have pointed out, you only need to cast one of the two variables in the operation as a float/double for that to work.

Comment: Thank you, I never thought of that !

Answer (score 4):

p and pMax must be of type int so you are performing an integer division. Cast one of the variables to float: `(p/(float) pMax)*100`.

Answer (score 2):

p and pMax probably are integers.

This results in integer/integer ... when pMax > p (likely) than the result is 0.
Then 0.0 is multiplied with 100 resulting in 0.0.

Solution: cast p or pMax to float or double.